# Presenting a UIPopover from a DisclosureButton in a UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uitableview

I'm trying to do something pretty simple, but I can't figure out how to anchor the popover to the DisclosureButton on a UITableViewCell.    Can anyone help me with a simple example of how to use presentPopoverFromRect that will properly anchor to the accessoryView?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using UIView's 
- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect toView:(UIView *)view
to convert the accessoryView's rect?

Comment: Perfect, that worked great.  Thanks for pointing me to it!  So, in my case, I was anchoring to a UITextField in a UITableViewCell, and the code ended up being CGRect theAnchor = [cell.contentView convertRect:textField.frame toView:baseTableView];

Comment: nice hint, but you'll need the rect before converting it. I found this answer very helpful to get the rect of the accessoryView: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11143908/388412