# how to display popover click on a tableview cell in ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

i am using a TableView in my application where i want a Pop over View when i clicked on a tabel cell, all the content which is in table Cell should display in a pop over view so plz suggest me how to do??

i have some sample code below which is not working..so suggest with code i want all the content in the cell to displayed in the pop over view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                                          initWithContentViewController:aView];
popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 416);
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:cell.bounds inView:cell.contentView 
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`UIPopoverController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference clearly states

> To display a popover, create an instance of this class and present it
>   using one of the appropriate methods. When initializing an instance of
>   this class, you must provide the view controller that provides the
>   content for the popover. Popovers normally derive their size from the
>   view controller they present

Your popoverController should have a view controller and not a view.

```
YourViewController *aViewController = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                                          initWithContentViewController:aViewController];
```

Then you can present this pop over

Comment: @7KV7: +1 for great answer..! :]

Comment: @7KV7 should i add new view controller in storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, but
You should have UIViewController instead UIView.

Answer (score -3):

you have to pass the view controller instead of view

Comment: Wont it be better to avoid duplicate answers to make the site more effective. Please up vote similar answers instead of duplicating