# Calling UIPopoverController from UITableView - objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

Is it possible to call `UIPopoverController` from parentViewController's tableView?
For example I've selected UITableViewCell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     //Call UIPopoverController here
}
```

If yes, please give short example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wanna do is use a custom table view cell, and inside your cell, create a button. For the button, and define your popover from the button touch up inside event function. This method works and I use it in my current project.

If you need, I can provide more details as it is not easy to describe the entire process in a few words.

However, you might wanna check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015400/how-to-correctly-present-a-popover-from-a-uitableviewcell-with-uipopoverarrowdir) out and see whether their solutions would help you.