# Present popover from cells accessory button?

Tags: ios, ipad, popover, cgrect, uitableview

I'm having a hard time presenting a popover correctly from the accessoryButton of a tableviewCell.

The reason I'm not using accessory view is because the cell is in edit mode and I couldn't display both the green plus sign + custom accessory view.. Maybe I overlooked something on that front?

Currently my popover shows correctly, but that's only the case for this configuration since I set a static distance from the origin...  Any Ideas how to solve this?

Code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (![self duplicateDayContent]) {
    duplicateDayContent = [[self storyboard]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CopyDay"];
    [duplicateDayContent setDelegate:self];

    duplicateDayPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:duplicateDayContent];
    duplicateDayPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600);

}

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x+800, cell.bounds.origin.y+10, 50, 30);

[duplicateDayPopover presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:cell permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: may be you would have considered cell.accessoryView.bounds or directly consider  cell.accessoryView.frame

Comment: thx a lot your your suggestion.  I tried:     CGRect rect = CGRectMake(cell.accessoryView.bounds.origin.x, cell.accessoryView.bounds.origin.y, 50, 30);
But that doesn't work on the x side. Maybe because I don't actually load an accesory view? or am i missing something?

Comment: cell.accessoryView.bounds.size.width-50 give a try using this in CGRectMake first argument

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015400/how-to-correctly-present-a-popover-from-a-uitableviewcell-with-uipopoverarrowdir

Comment: thank you again for your suggestion tirupathi, didn't solve it.  Rachels hint helped me, thank you!!  I somehow thought accessoryView is not valid because I use accessoryType. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 2):

This works quite nicely for a cell with `accessoryType .detailDisclosureButton`:

```
if let ppc = vc.popoverPresentationController, let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
    ppc.sourceView = cell
    ppc.sourceRect = CGRect(x: cell.bounds.width - 58, y: cell.bounds.height/2 - 11, width: 22, height: 22)
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
}
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You would typically do this in `tableView(_ accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath:)`

You can also test the position of the calculated frame with a marker:

```
let marker = UIView(frame: ppc.sourceRect)
marker.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
cell.addSubview(marker)
```

[image: Test marker]

Answer (score 1):

this code from this thread helped me: [How to correctly present a popover from a UITableViewCell with UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight or UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015400/how-to-correctly-present-a-popover-from-a-uitableviewcell-with-uipopoverarrowdir)
thanks to rachels hint

```
UIView *accessoryView       = cell.accessoryView; // finds custom accesoryView     (cell.accesoryView)
if (accessoryView == nil) {
    UIView *cellContentView = nil;

    for (UIView *accView in [cell subviews]) {
        if ([accView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            accessoryView   = accView; // find generated accesoryView (UIButton)
            break;
        } else if ([accView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITableViewCellContentView")]) {
            // find generated UITableViewCellContentView
            cellContentView = accView;
        }
    }
    // if the UIButton doesn't exists, find cell contet view (UITableViewCellContentView)
    if (accessoryView == nil) {
        accessoryView   = cellContentView;
    }
    // if the cell contet view doesn't exists, use cell view
    if (accessoryView == nil) {
        accessoryView   = cell; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift, this has worked for me:

Create a popover presentation segue, then use prepareForSegue to configure the UIPopoverPresentationController of the destination view controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == Storyboard.providerInfoSegue) {
        if let vc = segue.destinationViewController.contentViewController as? /*DestinationViewControllerType*/ {
           //Configure view controllers here

            if let popOverPresentationController : UIPopoverPresentationController = vc.popoverPresentationController {


                if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(selectedAccessoryIndexPath) {
                    var accessoryView: UIButton!
                    for accView in cell.subviews {
                        if accView is UIButton {
                            accessoryView = accView as? UIButton
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    popOverPresentationController.delegate = self
                    popOverPresentationController.sourceView                = cell
                    popOverPresentationController.sourceRect                = accessoryView.frame
                    popOverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections  = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Right

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```