# in custom tablecell popover not display and application crash?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, popover

In my program have table view.it has custom cell.

this custom cell has non editable textview.

when i touch this textview, popover popup.
it working well in ios6 simulator.

but ios5.1 simulator not working.
it gives this error message.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController
>   presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]:
>   Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a
>   window.'

in my custom cell view i put this code for touch event

```
ViewControllerDateIpcker *popView =[[ViewControllerDateIpcker alloc]init];
    popView.datedelegate = self;
    _popover =[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popView];

    [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:[_txtDate bounds]
                              inView:_txtDate
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                            animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
ViewControllerDateIpcker *popView =[[ViewControllerDateIpcker alloc]init];
        popView.datedelegate = self;
_popover =[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popView];

[_popover presentPopoverFromRect:[_txtDate bounds]
                                  inView:self.view
                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                animated:YES];
```

Comment: it gives error Property 'view' not found on object of type 'CellEdit*'.    CellEdit is my custom cell

Comment: then pass self.contentView. or you can pass the main uiview of the uiviewcontroller

Comment: i pass viewcontroller view to my cell and set it.now it work without app crashing.but it not coming from textview.it coming top of my viewcontroller

Comment: what about cell.contentView ?

Comment: in my table view has editable textview also.think it is text view one.popover textview is text view two.first i edit textview one.after i click text view two(key board that time pop up) the app crash.in ios6 simulator automatically keyboard hide and popup my popview.

Answer (score 0):

It is problem of bounds  only. You need to provide a view which has bounds.
You should try these answers. It has worked for me as well. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8416003/1372368 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/4512944/1372368