# Get frame for UITableViewCellAccessoryType

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessoryview

I want to present a popover. Currently I can retrieve the frame of the whole cell (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4512944/426227)). Is it possible to get the frame of the accessory (`UITableViewCellAccessoryType`)?

I want to retrieve the value in `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is to calculate the frame with fixed sizes. First you get the cell's frame with `rectForRowAtIndexPath`. Than you calculate the `accessoryType` frame. In my case I can give C# code, but you can translate it to Objective-C easily or roll your own solution:

```
int detailDisclosureSize = 24;
RectangleF accessoryPosition = new RectangleF(cellPosition.X + cellPosition.Width - detailDisclosureSize * 2.45f, cellPosition.Y + cellPosition.Height/2 - detailDisclosureSize/2, detailDisclosureSize, detailDisclosureSize);
```

`cellPosition` is the result from `rectForRowAtIndexPath`. Now you can translate it to the real coordinates with `convertRect:toView:`.

But the solution won't work if a new screen size comes out. Since there is currently no other solution I'll go with this or the whole cell size.

Answer (score -1):

in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGRect accessoryRect = cell.accessoryView.frame;
```

Comment: OK, one have to distinguish between `accessoryType` (what I want) and `accessoryView` (custom view). Is it possible to get the default frame for `accessoryType`?

Comment: Oh apologies, you wrote accessory view in your question. Does this return nil?

Comment: Yeah I confused myself a bit. `accessoryView` is nil, because I never set it (I only set the `accessoryType`). Do you have a solution for retrieving the frame of the accessory (`UITableViewCellAccessoryType`)? That would be nice.