# How do I get the size of a built-in accessory type in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to calculate the exact widths of subviews in a `UITableViewCell` where the cell `accessoryType` gets set to either `.checkmark` or `.disclosureIndicator` depending on certain factors.

These consumes part of the cell width with possibly some padding between them and the `contentView`.

Is there a way I can get a handle on these dimensions? Width/ height and padding of the `accessoryType` not `accessoryView`?

My calculation takes place in`tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` - so the cell is not yet rendered.

Comment: its returns as Int only , we can't handle\

Comment: see this once may be it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509740/get-frame-for-uitableviewcellaccessorytype?lq=1

Comment: I'd like to avoid dequeuing the cell in `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`?

Comment: Did you try `cell.accessoryView.bounds.size`

Comment: yea - it's nil. Although I think I'll end up implementing this eventually to create a view whose size is easy to get!

Comment: Why you can't run the application in simulator and exam frame of the indicator in a Interface debug mode? After that you can add these values into code and use them.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov - I have been doing that until to my surprise the size changes according to the device type?!?!

Comment: What is exactly do you want to achieve? May be exist other way to get same result.

Comment: I would like to implement accessibility throughout the app. Lots of table views there. Hence heights of each cell depends on its contents. Content includes labels that should resize according to content size category set by users. Hence  cell height should also change to accommodate the text and crop or truncate any. widths are essential to calculate the cell heights, it's also this bloody accessory type!

Comment: As I understand, you need calculate height of a cell via text and some other UI components. I think you should look at this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html . Autoresizing cells is very useful technology.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167596/discussion-between-ahmed-khedr-and-andrew-romanov).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
    UIScreen.main.bounds.width
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I'm trying to figure this out also.

One idea is this:

```
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
let contentWidth = contentView.bounds.size.width
let accessoryWidth = screenWidth - contentWidth
```

this would need to occur after the cell is rendered